Is it possible to make gf know variables?
I'm writing some PowerShell scripts on Windows and they contain references to other script like this:
& "$PSScriptRoot\install_scoop.ps1"

$PSScriptRoot equals the same directory as the current file.
Is there a way to make vim understand this so that gf works on these paths?
Currently I get this error message when I try opening the file using gf:

E447: Cannot find file "$PSScriptRoot\install_scoop.ps1" in path

Additionally, it would be ideal if $env:USERPROFILE was understood as $HOME, but vim doesn't seem to like having the colon there.

I answered a related question on SO a while ago. Maybe you can adapt it to your situation.

I would do:
let $PSScriptRoot='.'

Then gf should found it's way.

Thanks. That's a lot simpler than I was expecting.

Thanks for the feedback! I'm glad we could help you :-)

Ah, I've found a small issue where ctrl-x, ctrl-f completions replaces the variable with the dot now. I think the solution will have to be more complex to avoid this.
